# IIS: staticCompressionIgnoreHitFrequency does not work at a web-site level

Tags: iis

I am trying to delegate staticCompressionIgnoreHitFrequency IIS configuration attribute to a web-site level, so my users would be able to manage this setting independently.
I changed my applicationHost.config as follows:

1. In the `<configSections>` section in the system.webServer group, I configured settings for httpCompression element as follows:
   `<section name="httpCompression" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />`
2. Then I moved the whole httpCompression section from `<system.webServer>` into `<location path="" overrideMode="Allow">` section.
3. Then I configured httpCompression attributes: `<httpCompression directory="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\temp\IIS Temporary Compressed Files" staticCompressionIgnoreHitFrequency="False" lockAllAttributesExcept="staticCompressionIgnoreHitFrequency">`

In a web.config file at a test web-site, I added the following after the `<system.webServer>` element:
`<httpCompression staticCompressionIgnoreHitFrequency="True" />`
I restarted both AppPool and the web-site.

Still, whenever I request HTML-files from the web-site, GZIP-compression works for frequently accessed files only.